# Building an Angular 4 library while working on a project that depends on it

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I'm currently working on an Angular 4 project that involves the development of an external UI component library (much like "ngx-bootstrap").

Having the separation between the two is quite important because the said UI component library will later be used in additional Angular 4 projects.

What I've noticed is that most libraries come pre-built,
However, building them separately (at least right now) is too cumbersome, I'd much rather work on them simultaneously and the first idea that I've had was to simply import the `.ts` files and compile them from the parent project.

I tried achieving this functionality by using `npm link`, but when reading online, it seemed like this approach is not recommended.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/linked-library.md

I'd love to know what options I have in order to achieve this functionality.

Another important thing is to have the source available outside too, because the library will be developed *and* used in other projects.

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr) to build libraries with ease.

Follow this article. https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

you will get some idea. This will suit You I guess. Just create the component that you want to use as a library and export it.

1. Install angualr/cli  `npm install @angular/cli -g`
2. Create a component  `ng new my-component-library`
3. Create a module `ng generate module modules/header` [module that is going to act as library]
4. Create a component`ng generate component modules/header`
5. Export the header component

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent // <-- this!
  ]
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```

6. Install ng-packagr `npm install ng-packagr --save-dev`
7. As per the `ng-packagr` docs, we’ll need to add two files to our project, ng-package.json and `public_api.ts`. We’ll use `ng-package.json` to configure `n-packagr` and to tell it where to find our `public_api.ts` file, which we’ll use to export the feature modules of our component library. (Note: public_api.ts is a convention used by Angular component libraries.)

Add the following to ng-package.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
  }
}
```

And export your `header.module.ts` from `public_api.ts`:

```
export * from './src/app/modules/header/header.module'
```

Now we’ll add a packager script to our `package.json` that we can use to tell `ng-packagr` to package up our library according to the configuration of ng-`package.json`. Also, switch private to false so that you can publish your library when you need to.

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
},
"private": false
```

Now for the good stuff. Run `npm run packagr`, and once the process is complete you’ll find a dist folder in your project root. This is your component library. Fully self sufficient, packaged according to best practices, and ready to shine it’s red header-y light upon the world.

To PACK, run `npm pack dist` else you can publish directly `npm publish dist/`

#### Publish it on npm

Once you login to your npm account with npm login you can publish your component library with npm publish dist. Just be sure that you have a unique package name (hint: my-component-library may be taken). Once published, you’ll be able to install your component library from npm with npm install `my-component-library`.

#### Consuming your component library

Once installed, you can import your header component into any application’s app.module.ts, by including it in its @NgModule imports array…

```
import { HeaderModule } from 'my-package-name';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HeaderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And using its selector in a template as you would a component that is part of your application.

Source [medium.com](https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

Comment: Hey, that's really nice - however it still seems to require me to build and pack the library, and I indeed forgot to mention in my question that I need the source to be available outside too, because this library is not only going to be used by other Angular projects, it'll also be developed by others, outside of my current project

Comment: yes ng-packagr will help for that too. you can export as a library. I also had the same requirement as yours and I have been using it for some time. it is working as expected.

Comment: It seems like I have to package the library inside of a tar.gz for other projects to be able to use it though, or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: or you can directly follow what angular does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unICbsPGFIA&feature=youtu.be.but thats a typical work ng-packagr does the same.

Comment: yes.for example if the output of ng-packagr is in `build` folder. the you can do `npm pack build/`. so that you will get the tar.gz file you are looking for.

Comment: follow that article till the end. You will get all your answers.

Comment: Okay. was that answer okay now? Even without that once you enter the `ng-packagr` docs one can easily find what to do.

Comment: Didn't downvote either, however - as mentioned, the code will be developed outside of my project, therefore exporting a .tar.gz is not good for me, I want the source to be available.. the ideal solution would be to import simple typescript files

Comment: As I already mentioned. There is a solution. You have it and you are just not looking it in a way you wanted. All i can say is explore further. You will get it